# how to access text input value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

With this simple example, I want the p element to get the current value of text input but cannot figure out. The value doesn't change.

```js
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo";
    }
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML =   document.getElementById("myText").value;
```

```html
    Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">

    <p id="p1">Click the button to change the value of the text field.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: "I want the p element to get the current value of text input" — It does. As soon as you load the page, the p element gets the current (i.e. the default) value.

Comment: yeah, you need to have the second part bound to the input changing on the text field or when you click the button

Comment: I want to make a bidirectional search field with a ul list of names and and input text field. 1) when I click on a list element it puts the name in the text field and highlights the element in the list (this part works).

Comment: 2) the other part is to compare the value of text field and search in the list, if its finded the element get highlighted (but i cannot find a way to evaluate permantently the value of text input, it doesn't even change the p element (for demo) when writting in the text field)

Comment: Ok, I think the solution has to be with on change event, so it can change the value of text field every time its chsnges...

Answer (score 3):

Move that part of the code inside of your function. Currently, it only runs once and never again after the button is clicked.

```js
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo";
      document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML =   document.getElementById("myText").value;
    }
```

```html
    Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">

    <p id="p1">Click the button to change the value of the text field.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML =   document.getElementById("myText").value;
    }
```

```html
    Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">

    <p id="p1">Click the button to change the value of the text field.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Mind explained why you made this change? What's the problem with the OP's code?

Comment: More specifically I want to access the current value of text input from outside the function (to have a global var with the current value so I can use for other things)...For example, even when writting in the text field it should output that en the p element (independent from button)...

Comment: @AlfonsoMartinez: *"I want to access the current value of text input from outside the function"* You can call `document.getElementById("myText").value` anywhere you need the value.

Comment: That is what I'm doing in the example (calling document.getElementById("myText").value) outside the function, and it doesn't get updated...

Comment: @AlfonsoMartinez: *"and it doesn't get updated"* Every time you access `document.getElementById("myText").value`, you get the current value of the text field. It seems like you are accessing `document.getElementById("myText").value` at the wrong time, but without seeing your code, that's just speculation.

Answer (score 2):

Switch the location of two of your lines of code in the JS...

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myText").value;
}
document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo";
```

I'm guessing you wanted to start  the value off as Johnny Bravo, and then when the button is clicked, then set the innerHTML?